# Finding function from pattern

Tags: ida, x64dbg, game-hacking

I have been trying to reverse engineer a game for a while now. I have a pattern already for the function I want to find:

```
\x89\x54\x24\x10\x4C\x89\x44\x24\x18\x4C
\x89\x4C\x24\x20\x48\x83\xEC\x28\x48\x85
\xC9\x75\x08\x8D\x41\x2B\x48\x83\xC4\x28
\xC3\x4C
```

Can I find the function with that pattern using IDA or x64dbg?

Comment: Using IDA, do you mean the IDA debugger? (asking since the second software is a debugger)

Comment: @zi0Black Yes - at least I think I'm not 100% sure about the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IDA, you can find sequences of bytes via `Search->Sequence of bytes`. That said, if your byte pattern is poorly-chosen (for reasons such as that it includes relocatable byte sequences, or it was created for a different version of the software), the result of the search may well be that the pattern cannot be found in the target binary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It didn't really work but that's more of a problem on my side that I'll figure out. Not your fault at all. Thanks again for answering

Comment: No problem. If it doesn't match, try "reducing" your pattern, i.e., selecting some subset of it, and seeing if you can match the smaller one. Try to choose a long sequence that doesn't include any bytes that are interpreted as offsets or displacements.